# Drag and drop several bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, drag-and-drop

In my View, I want to move different bitmaps taken from a ListView , but with this method I can only drag one at a time

this is my method:

```
vestitiView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                text = (TextView)                          view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
                imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dressImage);
                bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
                dress = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                dragDrop();
                eliminated = false;
            }
        });

private void dragDrop() {
        dressAdded.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(dress,0,0,
                dress.getWidth(),dress.getHeight()));
        dressArea = new DressAreaView(this,dressAdded);
        frame.addView(dressArea);
    }

private class DressAreaView extends View {

        private GestureDetector gestures;
        private Matrix translate;
        private Bitmap dress;

        private Matrix animateStart;
        private Interpolator animateInterpolator;
        private long startTime;
        private long endTime;
        private float totalAnimDx;
        private float totalAnimDy;

        public void onAnimateMove(float dx, float dy, long duration) {
            animateStart = new Matrix(translate);
            animateInterpolator = new OvershootInterpolator();
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            endTime = startTime + duration;
            totalAnimDx = dx;
            totalAnimDy = dy;
            post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    onAnimateStep();
                }
            });
        }

        private void onAnimateStep() {
            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            float percentTime = (float) (curTime - startTime)
                    / (float) (endTime - startTime);
            float percentDistance = animateInterpolator
                    .getInterpolation(percentTime);
            float curDx = percentDistance * totalAnimDx;
            float curDy = percentDistance * totalAnimDy;
            translate.set(animateStart);
            onMove(curDx, curDy);
            if (percentTime < 1.0f) {
                post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        onAnimateStep();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public void onMove(float dx, float dy) {
            translate.postTranslate(dx, dy);
            invalidate();
        }

        public void onResetLocation() {
            translate.reset();
            invalidate();
        }

        public void onSetLocation(float dx, float dy) {
            translate.postTranslate(dx, dy);
        }

        public DressAreaView(Context context,List<Bitmap> dress) {
            super(context);
            translate = new Matrix();
            gestures = new GestureDetector(DressRoom.this,
                    new GestureListener(this));
            for(Bitmap b : dress) {
                this.setBitmap(b);
            }

        }



        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(dress, translate, null);
            Matrix m = canvas.getMatrix();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            return gestures.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        public void setBitmap(Bitmap dressing) {
            this.dress = dressing;
            this.translate.postTranslate(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

and this is my Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="rp.com.dressroom.View.DressRoom"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/personaView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="245dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkOut"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonShowTutorial"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add_shopping_cart" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/reset"
        android:layout_marginLeft="185dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#a79f9f"
        android:id="@+id/acquisti"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="231dp"
            android:layout_height="383dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CkeckOut"
            android:id="@+id/checkOutBtn"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Continua"
            android:id="@+id/continua"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
    </FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

How could I use that class to move several bitmaps?

[This is a screenshot of the layout with ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igyeb.png)